# Sharing layers with multiple branches

Tags: keras

Is it possible to share more complicated module with branching, let's say inception module for example?

I found answer for sharing simple sequential module [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45443410/930799) but it doesn't seem to be sufficient for my purposes.

I need to be able to do something like this:

```
def shared_module():
    a = conv()
    a = conv(a) 
    b = conv()
    p = concat([a, b])

shared = shared_module()
    m_x = shared(Input(shape))
    m_y = shared(Input(shape))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do any type of branching with Keras.

You should check the [Functional api](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/). It's exactly what you need. Also in the keras examples you'll find practical uses of it.